# Intellisense for XAML Files (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, intellisense

In Visual Studio 15, how do I get XAML Intellisense working for XAML files in Xamarin.Forms?

Edit: Split answer from the question

Comment: you should [edit] your question and split it with a question part and an answer part. You can answer your own question, you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution was found on [this forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4410ffe9-b0b1-40c2-ad5e-6f8c179b9dbd/xaml-intellisense?forum=wpf) by dzCepheus.

To resolve the problem, append the following 2 lines of code to the bottom of `catalog.xml`, which should be located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Xml\Schemas` (this depends on your local installation directory for visual studio).

The two lines of code being:

```
<Schema href="%VsInstallDir%/xml/schemas/xaml2006.xsd"
targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" />
```

**NOTE**: for me, "%VsInstallRoot%" worked, not "%VsInstallDir". It probably depends on the VS version.

and

```
<Association extension="xaml" schema="%InstallDir%/xml/schemas/xaml2006.xsd" />
```

After restarting Visual Studio, you will have IntelliSense and auto-complete + auto-fill working, but if the problem still occurs, make sure you have set "Source Code (Text) Editor" as Default Editor for the XAML file.

Comment: Thank you for editing/splitting my post into 2 parts @BrandonMinnick, I didn't know how to do it by myself as I am quite new to this forum.

Comment: You're welcome @RoloffM! When you get a chance, mark this answer as Accepted to help future developers who may have the same question! http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23139/347195